# Fiware cloud new instances, statuses and connection

Tags: fiware

How to create FiWare instance and connect it to internet?
I like the idea and I have big plans on using this infrastructure, but...

I've trying to create instance and make ssh connection to it for some time now.

- Created key-pair
- Created security group (22,3306,1)
- Created instance ubuntu 14 (also tried others)
- - Also tried ubuntu 12, POI and others already
- Added node-int-net-01 and node-int-noinet-net-02 to it when creating
- - Also tried already with 1 network only
- Allocated floating IP
- Associated it with the local IP that came from "node-int-net-01"

Statuses:

- Instance: ACTIVE, Power State RUNNING
- "node-int-net-01" networks in list: shared-subnet 192.168.192.0/18 Yes ACTIVE  UP
- Inside "node-int-net-01":
- - Network: Admin State: DOWN, Shared: No, External Network: No
- - Subnet: DHCP and all ok
- - Ports:  Status: BUILD, Admin State: UP

The confusing parts are (for clue, don't have to answer those if we have solution):

- How can network be EXTERNAL-SHARED-ACTIVE-UP and DOWN-NOT_SHARED-NO_EXTERNAL at the same time - perhaps there's an error
- What means Port status: BUILD, i mean it must have been building the port like 3 days already. Should i build there something, is it an order or status? Perhaps it means BUILT or BUILDING instead.
- What means instance ACTIVE? Is it still active (busy) and i should wait? Or it can be actively used already? From VM Display I never saw it going to unix prompt>, is it kind of fiware itself using this telnet instance? I rather saw things like
- "request error",
- "connection timeout",
- "socket.error",
- "Error 101   Network is unreachable".
- "cloud-init-nonet [13:31]: waiting 120 seconds for network device"
- numerous black-screens and never ending Booting from hard-disk
- from Instance log saw endless: "Waiting for network configuration", but that one was cured
- Thou i saw "localhost login prompt, but as i only created PEM, then
  cant imagine what to do with it - where do i get root/pwd? But i guess it was some error that it ended up there.

The latest status from Instance\Log is:

> cloud-init-nonet[4.52]: static networking is now up
>    * Starting configure network device[74G[ OK ]
>    * Starting Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
>    * Stopping Mount network filesystems[74G[ OK ]
>    * Stopping cold plug devices[74G[ OK ]
>    * Stopping log initial device creation[74G[ OK ]
>    * Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices[74G[ OK ]
>   Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Sat, 16 Apr 2016 01:23:11 +0000. Up 5.07 seconds.
>   ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+
>   ci-info: | Device |  Up  |     Address     |      Mask     |     Hw-Address    |
>   ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+
>   ci-info: |   lo   | True |    127.0.0.1    |   255.0.0.0   |         .         |
>   ci-info: |  eth0  | True | 192.168.242.127 | 255.255.192.0 | fa:16:3e:7a:47:94 |
>   ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+
>   ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
>   ci-info: | Route |  Destination  |    Gateway    |    Genmask    | Interface | Flags |
>   ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
>   ci-info: |   0   |    0.0.0.0    | 192.168.192.1 |    0.0.0.0    |    eth0   |   UG  |
>   ci-info: |   1   | 192.168.192.0 |    0.0.0.0    | 255.255.192.0 |    eth0   |   U   |
>   ci-info: +-------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------+-------+

For a ping and ssh i get:  "Destination Host Unreachable" and "No route to host"
Also tried allocating floating IP with "federation" pool, but with that IP i just got time-outs for ping and ssh

I read already:

- wiki
- fiware help
- stackoverflow
- Followed also the steps in this slideshow http://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/developing-your-first-application-using-fi-ware-20130903
- http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org/cosmos-gui/ seems to be down
- - EDIT: can use this one (need to use https and accept bad cert)
- http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.OpenSpecification.Data.BigData_R4#Basic_concepts
- http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/bigdata-analysis-cosmos/documentation - no info about it neither.

Any ideas? Perhaps there is an UI (other than the web page at https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/ that seems to be in early beta) for using FiWare (that can do all the "anyway-mandatory" steps for users (developers)?
Maybe the problem is that I'm a software developer not network administrator, and perhaps this interface is meant for linux network andministrators.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Error 101 Network is unreachable" shows that there was a problem in the VM network. node-int-net-01 is the shared network to be joined with the public network, while node-int-noinet-net-02 is to be joined with a network to use VPN. You shouldn't use both networks in the same VM, just you should use node-int-net-01.
The code messages like BUILD, ACTIVE and so on, are codes belonging to Openstack.
Regarding ping, you should open the icmp port in the security port to allow it.
Anyway, if you continue having problems, you can send a mail to FIWARE Lab support fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org, indicating your concrete data.